# How To Manipulate WMIObject String to write to file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

This seems extremely simple but I can't seem to find the syntax anywhere on how to do this.

My current script is:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Bios -ComputerName $Env:COMPUTERNAME |
    Select-Object SerialNumber |
    Out-File "$env:SystemDrive\IT Logs\serial.csv"
```

I'd like to manipulate it so that just the serial number and not the text that says "SerialNumber" above it is output to a single row .csv file.

My goal is to run this script on each computer and send the .csv file to a label printer for asset tags. Is this even possible?

Comment: Use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` instead of just `Select-Object`. Also, I would recommend a `.txt` extension on your file since in that case it will not really be a csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `\IT Logs\Serial.txt` file to contain the serial number of the current computer, you can write it this way:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_BIOS |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty SerialNumber |
  Out-File "$Env:SystemDrive\IT Logs\Serial.txt"
```

In this case the text file will contain only the serial number. If you want it in ASCII instead of UNICODE format, use `-Encoding ASCII` with `Out-File`.

If you really want a CSV file for output, you can write this:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_BIOS |
  Select-Object SerialNumber |
  Export-Csv "$Env:SystemDrive\IT Logs\Serial.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

In this case, we leave out `-ExpandProperty` to output the object (not just the property) and use `Export-Csv` to create a CSV file (rather than `Out-File`).

Answer (score 0):

Two ways for the first part of the problem of selecting just the value of the property.

The first being Bill_Stewart's commented suggestion:

```
Select-Object -ExpandProperty SerialNumber |
```

or alternatively:

```
(gwmi win32_bios -ComputerName $Env:COMPUTERNAME).SerialNumber
```

For your second issue of printing, you may be able to avoid the .CSV intermediate step by using something like [**Out-Printer**](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113367)